# JavaScript: not able to alert output value

Tags: javascript

The code is pretty simple.

HTML:

```
<div class="simpleDiv" id="Child1" onmouseover="expandDiv(this);"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.simpleDiv {
    background-color: red; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 50px; 
    margin: 5px; 
    margin-left: 50px; 
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function expandDiv(object){
    alert(document.getElementById(object.id).style.height);
}
```

Why am I not able to alert the height of the div like this? If I alert the id or class using the function hasAttribute, thats working fine but not able to alert the css properties of the elements.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Why not just `alert(object.style.height)`?

Anyway, the reason it doesn't work is because `elem.style.property` only works with inline `style="..."` attributes. To take into account all styles, you need this:

```
alert(window.getComputedStyle(object).height)
```

Older versions of IE don't support this, but it's a very easy shim:

```
window.getComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle || function(e) {return e.currentStyle;};
```

Comment: Even if I try     alert(object.style.height) , it doesn't work! Does it?   Thanks for the answer, by the way. the second one works!

Answer (score 2):

```
function expandDiv(object){



    alert(document.getElementById(object.id).innerHeight);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
alert(document.getElementById(object.id).offsetHeight);
```

Here is description: 
[offsetHeight on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.offsetHeight)

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery:

```
 alert($('#Child1').css("height");
```

Or to change the attribute, use:

```
$('#Child1').css("height", value )
```

Ignore if you don't want JQuery.